# css text size for links doesn't work

Tags: css

i've set the css code for links, but the text size doesn't work. Why?
What's wrogn with my code?
Thank you

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wZrt/1/)

CODE

```
  <h1> Clicca <a href='http://www.chitarrastudio.com/'><font size='2' face='Verdana'>QUI</font></a> per tornare su <a href='http://www.chitarrastudio.com/'><font size='2' face='Verdana'>Chitarra Studio!</font></a></h1>


      a:link{ 
        font-family: Oswald, Arial, Tahoma, Sans serif;
           font-size:38px;
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: #FF6600;
      } 

a:visited{  font-family: Oswald, Arial, Tahoma, Sans serif;
           font-size:38px;
        color: #d3d3d3; 
      } 

a:hover{ 
        font-family: Oswald, Arial, Tahoma, Sans serif;
           font-size:44px;
        color: #FF9900; 
        text-decoration: none;
      }
```

Comment: `<font>`, we meet again...

Comment: The <font> element is deprecated in HTML 4.01, why are you using it. Please use css instead of that.

Comment: Sorry guys. Maby for you it's a stupid thing, but i am not an expert, so i don't know many things. thank you everybody for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that inline style definitions will override any previous stylings. Take out the inline stylings in the  element and you'll be fine. Like so:

```
a:link{ 
    font-family: Oswald, Arial, Tahoma, Sans serif;
       font-size:38px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #FF6600;
  } 

a:visited{  font-family: Oswald, Arial, Tahoma, Sans serif;
       font-size:38px;
    color: #d3d3d3; 
  } 

a:hover{ 
    font-family: Oswald, Arial, Tahoma, Sans serif;
       font-size:44px;
    color: #FF9900; 
    text-decoration: none;
  }


<h1> Clicca <a href='http://www.chitarrastudio.com/'>
<font face='Verdana'>QUI</font></a> per tornare su 
<a href='http://www.chitarrastudio.com/'>
<font face='Verdana'>Chitarra Studio!</font></a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

the comment points the finger on the problem. with the font tag you overwrite your css settings. ("direct" html tags get a higher prio)... just remove size="2" or the complete font-Tag

```
<h1> Clicca <a href='http://www.chitarrastudio.com/'>QUI</a> per tornare su <a href='http://www.chitarrastudio.com/'>Chitarra Studio!</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline styling [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wZrt/5/)

```
<h1> Clicca <a href='http://www.chitarrastudio.com/'>QUI</a> per tornare su <a href='http://www.chitarrastudio.com/'>Chitarra Studio!</a></h1>
```